# Editing the graphic generated by ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I have generated a graphic using ListDensityPlot in Mathematica, I want to make following three edits to it, but not finding a way. Would be thankful for any advice.

1. How to rotate the graphic. My graphic is triangular in shape, I want to orient it in a fixed direction. How to make a particular corner to be at top, which can be identified with its Cartesian coordinates (say, by (0, 0)) ?
2. I want a fixed range to be shown by the false color scale to represent different colors on graphic. I am not able to do so as irrespective of the range I choose for PlotLegends, the scale shows only the range which is available on graphic.
   For example if the graphic has area having the plotted variable varying between 0 to 5, no matter what range i choose for PlotLegends->, false color scale only shows the colors representing the values 0-5 only. How to change it ?
3. Instead of leveling the three axes, I want to level the three edges with their coordinates (with no frame). How to achieve it ?

Here is the example for the truncated triangle.

```
XX1={{0.,0.,2},{0.149508,0.076178,7},{0.153488,0.0498713,7},{0.155716,0.0246631,4},{0.156435,0.,4},{0.302952,0.0984348,7},{0.307539,0.0487095,7},{0.309017,0.,4},{0.444473,0.144418,7},{0.451668,0.0715374,7},{0.453991,0.,4},{0.574342,0.186615,8},{0.584501,0.0925761,7},{0.587786,0.,4},{0.689152,0.223919,8},{0.702713,0.111299,7},{0.707107,0.,4}};
ListContourPlot[XX1,PlotLegends->{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},ColorFunction->"AvocadoColors"]
```

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using and some visuals explaining the desired result?

Comment: I have added a small example in the original post.

Comment: Still not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. For 1. and 3. maybe this? `ListContourPlot[XX1, PlotLegends -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 
 ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, PlotRangePadding -> None]`

Comment: Thanks. For point 2, the false color scale is having colors for 2-8. What I want is 0-8, even if there is no points in the list corresponding to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

`BarLegend` inside plot area.

```
ListContourPlot[XX1, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{"AvocadoColors", {0, 8}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkerSize -> 200], 
    {.28, .06}], 
 ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

For 1.

```
ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}
```

For 2.

```
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"AvocadoColors", {0, 8}}]
```

For 3.

```
PlotRangePadding -> None

ListContourPlot[XX1, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"AvocadoColors", {0, 8}}], 
 ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Though I have one more question. How to move the Legend Bar on the free area on the left (within the graphic area) with a decrease in size (so that it can fit into the free triangular space). I could find the method to put it at top/bottom/left/right, but not within the graphic.

Comment: @user49535 If this answer is acceptable, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If it is not, please explain why.